# Is there a specific word to describe the duration before due date?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word to describe the time period before a workflow/process should be completed.

Comment: You might talk about the "*execution phase*" although technically the execution phase can extend past the deadline if the program slips schedule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Oxford Dictionaries online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lead-time)...

> **lead time** *- the time between the initiation and completion of a production process*

(Pronounced "leed", not "led", obviously!)

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I want, only that lead time should better be applied in specific production process. Don't you think there is a word more general?

Comment: e.g. (1) Freshly elected politicians frequently forget to consider the amount of lead time required to get them re-elected on the next election cycle. (2) The lead time required to test and prep the software for general release date is about 6 weeks.

Comment: In US semiconductor fab and manufacturing, *lead-time* is a very important word in the process planning dept, due to parallel processes that has to occur and then concur at planned dates.

Comment: @Yufeng- For a more more general term it's simply *time*- as in, "You've still got time; it's not due 'til Thursday."

Comment: @Yufeng: As Blessed Geek's examples show, you're imposing an unnecessarily narrow definition on the word *production*. Native speakers are quite flexible about what "procedures intended to **produce** a result within a given timescale" can have a "lead time".

Comment: Might I please cajole you into including in plain text the origin of dictionary citations?  I know you’ve provided a link, and your source is beyond the peach or unimpalable or however the saying goes, but it would be optimal if it were named in plaintext. See the new meta question on attributions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**[Gestation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gestation#synonyms)** from Mirriam-Webster:

> 1: the carrying of young in the uterus (see UTERUS sense
>   1) : PREGNANCY
>
> 2: conception (see CONCEPTION sense 3) and development especially in
>   the mind

Example from same link:

> The book has been in gestation for a long time.

This comprehends the entire time period between conception (literal or metaphorical) and delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the **[run-up](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/run-up?q=run%20up)**

> The period preceding a notable event:
>   *an acrimonious run-up to legislative elections8

Comment: Thanks, 'run-up' looks like the preparation peroid before some process actually starts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be referring to the *[implementation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Implementation) period  or process*:

> the act of implementing (providing a practical means for accomplishing something); carrying into effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two suggestions:

term -(archaic)  A boundary or limit, especially of time.

In a not so ideal world, "window" would about do. It means an interval or opportunity for action.

Look these two up on Oxford.